# mysql "between and" query including the first day and the last day

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query that i use to extract data from my database but I discovered that it miss the first day and the last day. In this example, it skip the records that have 'scadenze' set as '01-05-2021' and miss the records that have 'scadenze' set as '31-05-2021'. How can I inlcude also these days?

This is the query that I use:

```
$anno = date('Y'); // CURRENT YEAR
$mese = (date('m')+1); // THE MONTH THAT I NEED (THE NEXT ONE)

// FIRST DAY OF THE MONTH

$giornoinizio = '01';
$a = '';
$a .= $anno . '-' . $mese .'-' . $giornoinizio;

// LAST DAY OF THE MONTH

$giornofine = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$mese,$anno);
$b = '';
$b .= $anno . '-' . $mese .'-' . $giornofine;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM condominio WHERE scadenze BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' ORDER BY scadenze ASC";
```

This query "works" but it cut out the first day and the last one.. How can I include them?

Thanks

Comment: What datatype is `scadenze` please

Comment: Sorry, it is "timestamp"

Comment: If your `$a` and `$b` contains dates without timepart then first day must be selected.

Comment: @Akina can you please explain me what does it mean, please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use date() function on ur colum

```
SELECT * FROM condominio WHERE date(scadenze) BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' ORDER BY scadenze ASC
```

Comment: It seems to work, I need to investigate more if it gives me all the records, for the moment it looks fine but I need a double check :)

Comment: If you have a timestamp column when you use between or any clause it searching also with the time, `date()` function will exclude time because that what you are providing for `$a` and `$b`  date format `'Y-m-d'`

Don't forget to select the best answer if all good for you, thanks!

Comment: all the informations you gave to me were/are good. So, is it possible to vote "+1" for all?

Comment: @P.Davide it doesn't matter :), just to make your QS as solved.

Comment: Yes you can UPVOTE as may answers as you like, An upvote just means this answer was helpful/useful. Often more than one fits that situation

Comment: Yes, I'll go for @RiggsFolly because it provide more details and secured way to handle that

Answer (score 3):

You are making life rather difficult for yourself.

You can simply get the 2 dates using this date code

```
$a = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of +1 month'));
$b =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of +1 month'));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM condominio WHERE scadenze BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' ORDER BY scadenze ASC";
```

> But this data concatentation into a query is a bad habit to get into it can encourage you to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174).
> Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
> You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
> in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query.

Not sure which extension you are using, so I can only suggest a PDO solution

```
$a = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of +1 month'));
$b =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of +1 month'));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM condominio
        WHERE scadenze BETWEEN :a AND :b 
        ORDER BY scadenze ASC";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([':a'=>$a, ':b'=>$b]);

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ( $results as $row ){
    // process each row
}
```

Comment: Im this project i use pdo but this query i think is 'safe' because it is triggered by a button and don't let the user input datas into it. But, please, tell me if I am wrong

Comment: @Strawberry Yup more mental aberration